# Pandas: Merge с логикой OR

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Как в *Pandas*'e сделать *inner* объединение таблиц по нескольким полям с логической операцией *ИЛИ*? Как условие `ON` в выражении `JOIN` в *SQL*? Функция `merge` позволяет получать лишь точные совпадения по нескольким полям (т.е, логическая операция *И*).

**Пример.** Есть датафреймы `df1` и `df2`, у них имеются два общих поля `A` и `B`, нужно произвести их слияние по условию `df1.A = df2.A OR df1.B = df2.B` Информация в таблице `df1` считается более приоритетной, то есть, если совпадение происходит только по одному полю (`A` или `B`), то значение второго берётся из `df1`.

**df1**:

```
#    A    B        C
0    104  peter    28
1    228  andre    10
2    89   paul     17
3    219  saul     14
```

**df2**:

```
#    A    B
0    104  jessy
1    230  andre
2    219  saul
3    126  amy
```

**result**:

```
#    A    B        C
0    104  peter    28
1    228  andre    10
2    219  saul     14
```

Comment: Трудно понять как именно вы хотите объединить DataFrame'ы без наглядного примера. Что должно происходить с дупликатами строк? Если мы в одной строке объединяем по столбцу `B` - что попадает в итоговую выборку в столбец `A` - значение из `df1` или из `df2` и т.д. Приведите небольшие примеры входных данных и того что вы хотите получить на выходе. Кстати когда мы делаем JOIN в SQL мы чётко указываем столбцы (значения) из каких таблиц мы хотим видеть в итоговой выборке...

Comment: @MaxU одна из таблиц считается более актуальной. Пример добавил.

Comment: Хммм... не очень удачный пример, т.к. в результирующую выборку ничего из `df2` не попало...

Comment: @MaxU почему же не удачный? Можно считать, что df2 служит для фильтрации df1, и именно это получилось. Это упрощённая версия задачи, которая была у меня на работе: нужно было оценить результаты акции, одна таблица с телефонами и ID клиентов, другая с активностью всех клиентов (аналог поля С в df1); если совпадает ID или тел (т.к одно из двух могло поменяться), то это нужный клиент, его активность нужно записать, а остальных клиентов не учитывать. Возможно, лучше эту задачу решать именно как фильтрацию с функцией loc, но решения ниже мне было достаточно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для простой фильтрации есть решение попроще:

```
In [12]: df1.query("A in @df2.A or B in @df2.B")
Out[12]:
     A      B   C
0  104  peter  28
1  228  andre  10
3  219   saul  14
```

или

```
In [17]: df1.loc[(df1['A'].isin(df2['A'])) | (df1['B'].isin(df2['B']))]
Out[17]:
     A      B   C
0  104  peter  28
1  228  andre  10
3  219   saul  14
```

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, Пандас не имеет встроенного функционала для такой операции. Для получения желаемого результата нам нужно выполнить независимые слияния датафреймов по желаемым параметрам, затем привести таблицы к единому формату, избавиться от дубликатов и объединить в итоговую таблицу:

```
# объединяем по полю А
mix1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['A'])
# приводим таблицы к единому виду
mix1['B'] = mix1['B_x']
mix1.drop('B_x', axis=1, inplace=True)
mix1.drop('B_y', axis=1, inplace=True)


# объединяем по полю В
mix2 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on=['B'])
# избавляемся от дубликатов (*)
mix2 = mix2.loc[mix2['A_x'] != mix2['A_y']]
# приводим таблицы к единому виду
mix2['A'] = mix2['A_x']
mix2.drop("A_x", axis=1, inplace=True)
mix2.drop("A_y", axis=1, inplace=True)


# конкатенация в итоговый датафрейм с новой нумерацией строк
result = pd.concat([mix1, mix2], ignore_index=True)
```

---

(*) Про дублиакаты. Слияние датафреймов по полю А даёт общие для двух таблиц строки, где равны А, они же включают в себя строки, где равны А и В. Аналогично слияние по В даст строки с общими А и В. Поэтому конкатенация этих двух таблиц даст строчки-дубликаты, в которых равны А и В. Поэтому во второй таблице делается фильтрация, в итоге которой остаются лишь строки с равными В, но не А, а результирующая таблица имеет по одному экземпляру из трёх необходимых комбинаций:

```
A_ |  AB
--------
__ |  _B
```